# Maven error: package com.google.common.collect does not exist

Tags: maven, jar, dependencies, pom.xml, guava

In my pom.xml file, I have added

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>11.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and I have downloaded the jar file from https://github.com/google/guava/releases/tag/v31.0.1 and added it to my build path.

Eclipse recognizes the import, as it does not give an error on the import line which is `import com.google.common.collect.Lists;`.

However, when I run `mvn package`, I get `package com.google.common.collect does not exist` even after cleaning the project.

Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: https://search.maven.org/search?q=com.google.guava Second you might need to define the `<type>bundle</type>` based on the packaging...Downloading manually is simply a misunderstanding of Maven. By defining it in your pom file it will be downloaded automatically from central repository...

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add `<scope>system</scope>` and `<systemPath>path</systemPath>`

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html more info here at the bottom

Comment: System scope usage is first deprecated and second simple wrong in such case...